# cutting bits in C++

Tags: c++, c

Suppose we have a binary file, that contains 32 bit numbers. Each 32bit number represents an instruction. My question: is it possible to cut this bits into chunks of 6+5+5+16 directly. Something like:

```
typedef struct _instruction
{
    int op_code : 6;
    int reg_dest : 5;
    int reg_s1 : 5;
    int offset : 16;
} INST, *PINST;

int read_32_bits = read_next_instr();

INST i = (INST)read_32_bit; /* this would cut the bits into chunks*/
```

Comment: Possible, yes. Portable, no! The relationship between bits in a word and bitfields in a structure varies.

Comment: C or C++? Pick one. The code you've written suggests the former, not the latter.

Comment: I prefer C++. But I will settle for either one!

Comment: I gave you an answer that's more portable than the one you selected and won't invoke undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an answer that will work, be portable, not invoke undefined behavior on any compiler, and be optimized fairly effectively:

```
struct instruction {
   typedef unsigned int uint_t;

   explicit instruction(uint_t val) : val_(val) {}
   instruction(uint_t op_code, uint_t reg_dest, uint_t reg_s1, uint_t offset)
     : val_((op_code & 0x3fu << 26) | (reg_dest & 0x1fu << 21) |
            (reg_s1 & 0x1fu << 16) | (offset & 0xffffu))
   {
   }

   uint_t op_code() const { return (val_ >> 26) & 0x3fu; }
   void op_code(uint_t newval) { val_ = (newval & 0x3fu << 26) | (val_ & 0x3ffffffu); }

   uint_t reg_dest() const { return (val_ >> 21) & 0x1fu; }
   void reg_dest(uint_t newval) { val_ = (newval & 0x1fu << 21) | (val_ & 0xfc1fffffu); }

   uint_t reg_s1() const { return (val_ >> 16) & 0x1fu; }
   void reg_s1(uint_t newval) { val_ = (newval & 0x1fu) << 16) | (val_ & 0xffe0ffffu); }

   uint_t offset() const { return (val_ >> 16) & 0xffffu; }
   void offset(uint_t newval) const { val_ = (newval & 0xffffu) | (val & 0xffff0000u); }

   uint_t &int_ref() { return val_; }
   uint_t int_ref() const { return val_; }

 private:
   uint_t val_;
};
```

This lets you access all of the bitfields with a very convenient notation. I think it's also a POD, which lets you use it in a few interesting ways. And a good compiler will do a fairly decent job of optimizing the bit munging operations, especially if you have several calls to the convenience functions in a row.

It's almost as nice as having an overlay bit field. It's just a bit more work to define in the first place.

Also, I changed the type to `unsigned int` because if you're fiddling around with the bits, you really want a simply represented number without a sign bit or anything funky like that. Ideally you'd be including the `<cstdint>` header and using `::std::uint32_t` or something in the typedef at the top.

Answer (score 6):

Why not create a bit structure like you have but then place it inside a union?  I dropped the typedef so it uses C++ style definitions.

```
struct instruction
{
    int op_code  : 6;
    int reg_dest : 5;
    int reg_s1   : 5;
    int offset   :16;
};

union INST
{
    instruction  a;
    uint32_t     b;
};
```

You could store/load the 32-bit values using network functions:

```
INST  i;
i.b = ntohl(value);
```

And now you can reference the bit fields without typecasting.

```
if (i.a.op_code == XXX)
```

Comment: Just make sure the endianness and bit order is correct, depending on the compiler and target CPU.

Comment: Also C++ prohibits writing to one member of a union and then reading from a different member. It invokes undefined behavior. I believe C99 allows it but before that C prohibited it as well.

Comment: @bames53 I'm looking through the C spec (ISO/IEC 9899:TC3) now and I can't find what you are referring to. Footnote 82 on page 73 (6.5.2.3) refers to it as type punning.  This might be a trap representation. So I don't believe it is prohibited otherwise wouldn't the `reinterpret_cast` also be prohibited?

Comment: @bames53: Yes, I believe you are incorrect. In fact, I believe this is one of the very few valid ways of changing the types of certain things **without** invoking UB.

Comment: @JamieRoyer I think there's more to it than that footnote, but I can't find it at the moment. As for reinterpret_cast, the result can't be used for anything except casting back to the original type, except in some specific circumstances. So `int i = 1; float f = *reinterpret_cast<float*>(&i);` _is_ UB. My understanding is that to do such conversions legally (with implementation defined behavior) you have to do something like use memcpy. I.e. `int i; float f; memcpy(&i,&f,sizeof(i));`

Comment: @Omnifarious Reading from a non-active member of a union is definitely undefined behavior in C++. It's possible to play some tricks with pointers to union members, but then you'll run into strict aliasing rules.

Comment: @bames53: Well, IMHO, that's a standard bug then. It should be unspecified what values you will get out, but not undefined behavior. There are some low-level things you can only accomplish by doing stuff like that.

Comment: @Omnifarious I can't think of anything that absolutely requires it and for which there's no alternative. Anyway C++ and even C disallow a lot of things that one might do in assembly. There's some good info on the benefits of undefined behavior here: http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html

Comment: @bames53: I've read that. :-) I think unions are an interested and uncommon case in which it's useful to narrow the scope of undefined behavior in certain ways. A hardware register that has a different structure on read than on write is an example I can think of. Other examples are simply very convenient. Being able to overlay a struct on type of a byte string, for example, as a message decoding technique. Or what this guy wants to do.

Answer (score 4):

You can just cast your struct as a pointer to the address of your 32-bit data.

```
INST* i = (INST*)&read_32_bit;
```

Then you could access your fields, like this:

```
printf("opcode = %x", i->op_code);
```

Comment: as Jerry mentioned, the struct order can be platform dependent

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal, what is your problem?  It is tagged with C, this code is correct unless you care to point out a problem

Comment: +1: useful. True, this is theoretically "undefined behavior", and in practice it won't be portable: it will depend on whether integers are 32 bits, whether they're stored as little-endian or big-endian integers, and so on. Nonetheless, it's likely to work, and if it *doesn't*, due to endianness issues, it will show the OP exactly why it's completely impossible on his/her system (due to the bits in the integer not being laid out the same way as the bit-fields).

Comment: I can't see a problem with this either - portability is important, but we are assuming, we don't know the OP's predicament. It may be fine in his scenario to use bit fields, and in the past I've found this approach to be more efficient than a bunch of shifts...

Comment: @TJD - The standard only guarantees that the bitfields get the number of bits indicated. It doesn't say anything about how they are stored inside the struct, like their order or padding.

Comment: If portability is important, you just declare multiple versions of your struct with #ifdefs based on platform to select the correct bit ordering

Comment: @BoPersson, that is a fair point.  If you want to be a purist, don't do this.  But on any particular real platform/compiler there will be a mapping you can use, and it can be pretty practical to do so.

Comment: This is actually the norm in embedded systems. I have seen way worse things than this. +1.

Comment: +1 The guarantees of the standard are just that, guarantees, but just because it isn't guaranteed that every conforming implementation supports something doesn't mean that it isn't supported in practice, or that it isn't supported on the target platform. The OP should be aware of the limitations, but the information should not be denigrated with absurd and uninformative nonsense about "naive myths and lies".

Comment: TJD you cannot use ifdef for platforms of different endianness, as those bit-fields are crossing byte boundaries, and in diiferent endiannes parts of bit-fields will be misaligned.

Comment: Thanks moderators for deleting the very valid reason that I downvoted this answer. @TJD: Jerry explains the problem; did you not see it?